# Insert an image before another already cited

Tags: graphics, floats, cross-referencing

I know is not the best, but I'd like to display an image before another already referred. I mean I'd like to cite image 2 before image 1 but display them in the correct order. This is becasue image 1 is very small and I want to display it at the top (or bottom of the page) while image 2 is very big and is iserted in its own page.

LaTeX correctly display images in the order I recall them in the text, but I'd like to avoid this, but only for these two images.

> E.g.
>
> Text text text see Image 2. Text text text see Image 1.
>
> Display image 1 in the same page (top or bottom).
>
> Newpage with image 2.

How can I do this?

Thankyou!

Comment: Of course I tryed with [h!] but is not effective.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works. But don't do this.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
  Text text text see Image~\ref{fig:B}. Text text text see Image~\ref{fig:A}.
  \begin{figure}[htb]
    \centering
        \includegraphics[width=4in]{example-image-a}
    \caption{Caption here}
    \label{fig:A}
  \end{figure}
  %\clearpage  %% uncomment if needed to shipout all floats before this point.
  \begin{figure}[htb]
    \centering
        \includegraphics[width=4in]{example-image-b}
    \caption{Caption here}
    \label{fig:B}
  \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

For more information on float placement, see [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/39020/11232)  by Frank.

Answer (score 2):

This can easily be resolved by using the `float` package in conjunction with the parameter `[H]`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{float}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[H]
...picture code...
\label{fig:figA}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[H]
...picture code...
\label{fig:figB}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

By using the `[H]` option the figure will appear exactly where you put the code. So you can define the order manually.